# Phonegap app Content-Security-Policy

Tags: ios, cordova, content-security-policy, phonegap-cli, phonegap-developer-app

I'm bulding an app with cordova. I'm using `phonegap serve` to load the app with phonegap developer app.

In `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap: file: tel: *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

(I've also tried without `file: tel:`, result is the same)

I can verify that this is prepared correctly in `platforms/browser/www/index.html`

Then I open phonegap app in iPad, I run `phonegap serve`, I open Safari development tools, press connect and there it is:

```
Refused to load gap://ready because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

In `index.html` I can see that the directive has been transformed to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Is there a way to make ipad to load the directive correctly?

*EDIT*

I've also tried to compile phonegap app developer with CSP directive in `index.html`, result is the same

**EDIT - 1**

I've also downloaded the zip file from `http://192.168.1.130:3200/__api__/appzip` (this is where I have my `phonegap serve` server) and `index.html` is already transformed!

The strange here is that `platforms/browser/www/index.html` is not transformed, so there is some process in-between that is transforming the CSP.

In my `config.xml` I've this directives:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />

<!-- Allowed WebView navigations -->
<allow-navigation href="http://*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="about:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="gap:*" />
<!-- Allowed URLs to be opened from the app -->
<allow-intent href="http://*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<allow-intent href="cdvfile://*" />
```

Comment: Do you have any plugins? Maybe some of the plugins overwrite the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

It was related to this issue: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1361

Mainly, bash was detecting that v6.4.2 and pointing to it (`which phonegap` was pointing to correct version) but when executing `phonegap` from command line, it was executing v6.0.2, which probably was not setting up the correct CSP.